# cannot subtract `T` from `T` in rust

Tags: generics, rust

I'm making a `point` `struct` containing 2 values `x` and `y` and a `line` `struct` containing two values `first_point` and `second_point` all these structs are generic type so I wanted to make a member method for `Line` struct but it's saying `` cannot subtract `T` from `T` ``

```
impl<T> Line<T> {

    fn len(&self) -> T {
        let x = (self.second_point.x) - (self.first_point.x) ;
        let y = (self.second_point.y) - (self.first_point.y) ;
        return ((x * x) + (y * y)).sqrt() ;
    }
}
```

This is the error by the ways:

```
error[E0369]: cannot subtract `T` from `T`
  --> src/sources.rs:19:39
   |
19 |         let x = (self.second_point.x) - (self.first_point.x) ;
   |                 --------------------- ^ -------------------- T
   |                 |
   |                 T
   |
help: consider restricting type parameter `T`
   |
16 | impl<T: std::ops::Sub<Output = T>> Line<T> {
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0369]: cannot subtract `T` from `T`
  --> src/sources.rs:20:39
   |
20 |         let y = (self.second_point.y) - (self.first_point.y) ;
   |                 --------------------- ^ -------------------- T
   |                 |
   |                 T
   |
help: consider restricting type parameter `T`
   |
16 | impl<T: std::ops::Sub<Output = T>> Line<T> {
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0369`.
```

I'm a beginner in Rust so I would really appreciate it if you can help me with this:

And this is the full code if you are interested

```
pub fn test_function() {
    
    let line = make_a_line(make_a_point(10, 20),  make_a_point(10, 20));
    
}
struct Point<T> {
    x:T,
    y:T
}

struct Line<T> {
    first_point: Point<T>,
    second_point: Point<T>,
} 

impl<T> Line<T> {

    fn len(&self) -> T {
        let x = (self.second_point.x) - (self.first_point.x) ;
        let y = (self.second_point.y) - (self.first_point.y) ;
        return ((x * x) + (y * y)).sqrt() ;
    }
}

fn make_a_point<T>(x_axix:T, y_axis:T) -> Point<T>{
    Point{x: x_axix, y: y_axis}
}

fn make_a_line<T>(start: Point<T>, end: Point<T>) -> Line<T> {
    Line{first_point: start, second_point: end} 
}
```

Comment: Since `T` can in principle be anything, there's no guarantee that it's a type that can be subtracted. The compiler error tells you how to fix it: ``consider restricting type parameter `T` ``.

Comment: You might also want to look into the [num-traits](https://crates.io/crates/num-traits) crate, which makes this a lot easier.

Comment: This is not a simple abstraction. While it is possible to define the sqrt function for integers, the result must be a float in order to cover all possible outcomes. I can only imagine two possible types for T in your use case: float or array/vector of floats. If you want to minimize code for float usage you can do so by requiring the Float trait from num-traits as suggested above or by defining your own minimalistic version of it.

Comment: I tried replacing the T with i32 for the ```impl``` alone but then it was saying ``` cannot subtract `i32` from `i32` in rust ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make operators like `+`, `-`, and `*` work for a type (`T` in this case), the operator-specific `std` traits must be implemented for it: [`std::ops::Add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html), [`std::ops::Sub`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Sub.html), [`std::ops::Mul`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Mul.html).
`T` must then be constrained, such that it implements them.
Correcting your code for this could look like this:

```rust
pub fn test_function() {
    
    let line = make_a_line(make_a_point(10, 20),  make_a_point(10, 20));
    
}
struct Point<T>
    where T: std::marker::Copy + std::ops::Sub<Output=T> + std::ops::Mul<Output=T> + std::ops::Add<Output=T>,
{
    x:T,
    y:T
}

struct Line<T>
    where T: std::marker::Copy + std::ops::Sub<Output=T> + std::ops::Mul<Output=T> + std::ops::Add<Output=T>,
{
    first_point: Point<T>,
    second_point: Point<T>,
} 

impl<T> Line<T>
    where T: std::marker::Copy + std::ops::Sub<Output=T> + std::ops::Mul<Output=T> + std::ops::Add<Output=T>,
{

    fn len(&self) -> T {
        let x = (self.second_point.x) - (self.first_point.x) ;
        let y = (self.second_point.y) - (self.first_point.y) ;
        return ((x * x) + (y * y)) ;
    }
}

fn make_a_point<T>(x_axix:T, y_axis:T) -> Point<T>
    where T: std::marker::Copy + std::ops::Sub<Output=T> + std::ops::Mul<Output=T> + std::ops::Add<Output=T>,
{
    Point{x: x_axix, y: y_axis}
}

fn make_a_line<T>(start: Point<T>, end: Point<T>) -> Line<T>
    where T: std::marker::Copy + std::ops::Sub<Output=T> + std::ops::Mul<Output=T> + std::ops::Add<Output=T>,
{
    Line{first_point: start, second_point: end} 
}
```

Notice 2 things: I also have `T` implement `std::marker::Copy`, as that makes it easier to work with the operator traits.
Additionally, you used the `srqt()` function. However this function is only available for the specific types `f32` and `f64`. I simply removed the call in the above code to make it compile for integers. If you really need such a function maybe the [num-traits](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.14/num_traits/?search=sqrt) crate can help you out, as @Ibraheem Ahmed pointed out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help you prevented me from hating rust, 
since I'm from a java background I'm not exposed to such strictness, 
I'm really grateful for your help, as for sqrt() i did this ```Clone + std::convert::Into<f64>``` then 

```let x = ((self.second_point.x) - (self.first_point.x)).clone().into(); 
let y = ((self.second_point.y) - (self.first_point.y)).clone().into();```